# Dice not resting horizontally in the Plane in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

[image]

Currently i am making Dice(Dice is a rigid body, has box collider) rolling. I have 6 dice in the box(the box is actually made up of plane and wall which is cube, it has a box collider). User can roll the dice by clicking the button, each of the dice is applied with the random force in random direction.

Now after sometimes the dice rests, but instead of resting horizontally on the plane some times the die rests in the unexpected position such as inclined with walls and even sometimes inclined within itself.

What i am doing currently?
I have checked if the die is sleeping and if it is sleeping and not parallel with horizontal, i am changing the transformation value. But the problem is it is slow and takes much time.

I want to rest them in the plane horizontally in a better and fast way.

Comment: Upload you **image** here not somewhere else. You like was broken

Comment: Can you share the code by which you are rolling the dice
Or try to Make your dice a bit heavy for gravity to act on it nicely

Comment: Have you tried changing the friction settings of the physics material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting up your Drag and Mass on your rigid body :)

Comment: @SudeepAcharya how about the bouncy materials . did you try it?

Comment: I have not tried. Can you elaborate more on this. Thank You

Comment: When choosing a material in your collider you can set the bounciness.

Comment: Yeah but it does not works always, sometime the problem occurs, i kept the physic material in the walls

Comment: Then try setting your drag and mass to a 15 value and also try checking the  **use gravity** and **use kinematic**